# Gulp-sass not compiling css on win7

Tags: windows, sass, gulp

I have a problem with compiling css with gulp-sass on win7.

Tasks in console run without errors, changes in html-files works correctly, but there is no compiled css file output

P.S.
I've started same on Mac and it works

Here is my gulpfile:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

    gulp.task('sass', function() {
        return gulp.src('app/sass/main.sass')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
    })

gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
    browserSync({
      server: {
        baseDir: 'app'
      },
      notify: false
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'sass'], function(){
    gulp.watch('app/sass/main.sass', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you forget `;`

Comment: If you meant ";" after "sass"-task - I've just added, but it not helps.But thanks for reply, pal